# Track changes in column paste to new sheet with date it changed

Tags: excel, vba

Can you please help me make a VBA Script that will track Column A:B in sheet1

If there is a change in existing values (Either A, B or Borth), or if a whole new value is added it will take the changes and posts it in sheet 2 A:B

Sheet2 need lastrow so i always have "Log" of the changes and it need to paste time when the change happened.

Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. "Can you help me make..." is usually not a well received question on this website. Try to make a first attempt of code and post it here. We will gladly help you to make sure it works afterwards.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve